# Can you free a grounded boat?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

It happened to me a few times that I accidently drove a boat on ground and it wouldn't move forward or backward. Is there some way to get a stranded boat back into water?

Comment: @TimmyJim If tried that to a car during a missions, wouldn't move an inch ...

Answer (score 1):

There's no mechanic in the game to achieve this specifically.

But depending on the boat and with a bit of luck you might be able to push it back in the river with a car.

I tried this with a high-car (a SUV) and a very flat low boat. While I didn't push the boat back in the river, I did manage to move it a little bit.